# Return object of a minimum

Tags: r, function, combinations

I have a list of

```
test = c("GDP","Infl","Unempl","OilPrices")
```

both of which are variables in my workspace.

I firstly used

```
CombSet(c("GDP","Infl","Unempl","OilPrices"), c(2), repl = FALSE, ord = FALSE, as.list = FALSE)
```

to retrieve all 2 combinations of two variables, that I would like to use in the model. ALL of them, GDP, Infl, Unempl and OilPrices are ts objects with the same length. If the vector from Combset contains GDP and Infl for instance, how can I turn the text into a function? Meaning that I retrieve the time series of GDP and Infl?

Comment: Do you need something like `combn(mget(test), 2, simplify = FALSE)` ?

Comment: For example, `lm(getElement(object = .GlobalEnv, "GDP") ~ getElement(object = .GlobalEnv, "Infl"))`

Comment: @RonakShah exactly!!! thanks a lot, did not know such a function exists ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get all the `test` objects in a list and then use `combn` to select 2 at a time.

```
combn(mget(test), 2, simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: I got one little issue ... what if I had "GDP23" in my simulation and it should return GDP^2 (test$GDP^2) dataset and GDP^3 (test$GDP^3) dataset. Is there any way to return these two? What I intended to say is that in case of a specific variable in test "GDP23", I need a second and third polynomial of that variable.

Comment: @Michael Is this the only one that is different? What if you have a an actual object called "abc23" for which you don't want `abc ^ 2` and `abc ^ 3` but only return `abc23` as it is. How do you differentiate between them ?

Comment: in fact, I have GDP23, YC23, Debt23 and ST23, all of which should return 2 and 3rd polynomials of their respective functions ... its a bit complicated, but probably the only way how to do it through a simulation since I always need polynomial in their case, but in the rest, I do not use the two polynomials but directly the function.

Comment: @Michael I see okay. But I think this is completely different question from your original post which requires completely different treatment. Would you mind posting it as a separate question ?